# Error in Displaying ads in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using the `AlexTouch.googleAdMobAds` project for displaying ads. Unfortunately it shows the error below:

```
static  UIWindow  window;
    static GADBannerView adViewWindow; 

    static  bool adOnWindow = false;
```

[image]

Error:
 Error CS0012: The type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly`monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' (CS0012) (OnlineVideos.Ui)

How can I solve this issue? Can anyone help please?

Comment: FYI: Do not post errors as screen snapshots as the search indexing will not be able to help other users that have this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a using clause to include `UIKit`:

`using UIKit;`

#### `Xamarin.iOS` Only Nuget:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds" version="7.6.0.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

#### UPDATE 2: `Xamarinos.AdMob.FormsPlugin` Nuget

A `Xamarin.Forms` based PCL version @ https://github.com/LosXamarinos/Xamarinos.AdMob.FormsPlugin

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarinos.AdMob.FormsPlugin/

#### UPDATE: See this forum thread concerning AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds being outdated:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7935/admob-with-alextouch-googleadmobads

> I am the author of AlexTouch.GoogleAdMobAds it is really outdated now please use either the component
>
> https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleadmob/
>
> or the more up to date binding
>
> https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAdMobAds
>
> I would suggest the component over the manual binding it's just easier ;)

Comment: @Ramanil I updated my answer, appears that AdMob wrapper is really outdated and obsolete.

Comment: @Ramanil Here is a `Xamarin.Forms` based PCL version @ https://github.com/LosXamarinos/Xamarinos.AdMob.FormsPlugin Updated Answer

Comment: I am not using Xamarin.forms and Monotouch. I am using xamarin.Ios project so please help me for getting xmararin.ios SDK

Comment: @Ramanil If you want a `Xamarin.iOS` only interface, then use the Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds Nuget I remove the Xamarin.Forms tag from your question to clarify this.